# Condition on open cover in definition of sheaf in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne, p.61, definition of a presheaf. The condition (3) reads:

*if U is an open set, if {$V_i$} is an open covering of U, and if $s \in \mathscr{F}(U)$ is an element of such that $s|_{V_i} =0$ for all $i$ then $s =0$.*

Since the restriction can only be defined if $V_{i} \subseteq U$ for each $i$, should’nt there be an additional condition on the cover, for example *the union of subsets in the cover must be equal to $U$* ?

Comment: "the union of subsets in the cover must be equal to U ?" Isn't that excactly what an open covering is?

Comment: In an open cover the covered element is included in the union, but there is no condition that each element in the cover must be included in the covered element. Am I wrong  ?

Comment: If each of the $V_i$ is contained in $U$, surely $U \supseteq \cup V_i$?

Comment: But Hartshorne only mentions that {$V_i$} is an open cover. No condition is specified on the individual $V_i$.

Comment: An open cover of a space $X$, is a family of open subsets $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of X, st $X=\bigcup_i U_i$.

Comment: In the Wikipedia definition of an open cover  it is inclusion or equality. Hence my confusion.

Comment: It does not really matter since you can always take the intersections $U\cap V_i$ to produce an equality. So you can take any covering in the sense of Wikipedia as well, but then you have to interpret $s\vert_{V_i}$ as $s\vert_{V_i\cap U}$.

Comment: Thank you. I am happy that this is just about the definition of an open cover. When I asked the question I feared I missed something more fundamental on the definitions of sheaf / presheaf.